# how to pass selected date to ajax load in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i am trying to pass selected date into function.

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' , 
        onSelect: function(){
        $("#container").load("sample.php", { "mydate": "howtogetselecteddate"});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) callback takes two arguments, the first one containing the selected date:

```
$('#pickdate').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#container').load('sample.php', { mydate: dateText });
    }
});
```